# how to include rel="author" in your own website?

Tags: semantics, markup, author, rel

As far as I know the rel attribute should only be used with a link, so my current approach

```
<h1><span rel="author">Peter M......</span>'s website</h1>
```

seems to be invalid (even though it's working with Google's rich snippet validator). So how would I use the rel="author" attribute when I don't want to link to any external websites like g+, twitter, ... (a link (on my website) pointing to my own website doesn't quite make sense to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to [validate authorship with an email address](https://plus.google.com/authorship) if you have one for the domain of your site.

You said you don't want to use external links, but something like

`<link href='https://plus.google.com/[your G+ id]' rel='author'/>`

has worked fine for me.

[Schema.org](http://Schema.org) is apparently quite unpredictable. You should probably mark a [person](http://schema.org/Person) as an author, which means you might need a lot of markup.

Comment: I like google+, but it feels kinda odd to rely on such an "external service" (if g+ ceased to exist, my identity could not by evaluated any more) :/

@schema.org: oh yeah, I should've thought of that, I've been using it anyway ^^